# What is the difference between Sodium Nitrate and NaNH3

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have almost no experience in chemistry so please excuse my ignorance. I am looking to purchase some Sodium Nitrate but the vendor I am dealing with has the chemical formula NaNH3 listed beside the Sodium Nitrate they sell. Just wondering what the difference is?

Comment: are you sure it's not NaNO3?

Comment: Maybe NaNH2 sodamide not NaNH3? But a simple typo as @costrom suggests NaNO3 makes more sense

Comment: Heres this listing I have. https://www.glengarrycheesemaking.on.ca/rennet-and-ingredients/ingredients/sodium-nitrate-en/sodium-nitrate-1-kg.html

Comment: So If I am understanding correctly, there is no chemical with the formula NaNH3 ? And its more than likely a typo.

Comment: Correct there is no such chemical as $\ce{NaNH3}$. A typo on the webpage is the only thing that makes sense. Since this is from website for making cheese, I doubt that there is much chemistry knowledge there.

Comment: Yes it's a typo, that is repeated a few times in the link. It would suggest the website author/updater is not of a chemical persuasion! NaNO3 is sodium nitrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\ce{NaNO3}$ (which we established is the de-typo’d version of what your source calls $\ce{NaNH3}$) is simply the chemical formula of sodium nitrate.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like this is just a typo on the part of the web developer. There is no such thing as $\ce{NaNH3}$. They probably meant to type $\ce{NaNO3}$.